# How to access the 2nd screen in a dual screen Android phone with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile

I'm starting to work on a project where we need to access the 2nd screen of a dual screen phone, we are using Xamarin.  I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.  Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: First you need to determine which Android APIs allow you to do this, and if they are standard or something special provided by the device vendor.

Comment: As Jason stated, there are custom APIs from some vendors for their multi-screen devices... If it is one that is based of of the ASOP multi-screen support, then that second screen is a presentation output and is handled by `Presentation` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation

Comment: Thank you both for responding.  I can't find anything in Xamarin documentation with sample c# code for the Presentation class.  Am i missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do in Xamarin.It need Android API,and in CustomRenderer to use API.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are focused on second external screens, which is mostly what was around in 2019 :)

Now there are multiple dual-screen devices, including the Microsoft Surface Duo, and a couple of different styles from Samsung (Galaxy Fold/2, Galaxy Flip).

If you're using **Xamarin.Forms**, there's a `TwoPaneView` layout control that specifically detects and adapts to dual-screens, and also a `DualScreenInfo` helper class for device metrics. [Get started docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dual-screen/xamarin/) and [more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dual-screen/) are available on learn.microsoft.com. Check out these [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/dual-screen/xamarin/samples) and this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/surface-duo-sdk-xamarin-samples/). These APIs are currently hardcoded for the *Surface Duo* device.

If you're using **Xamarin.Android**, you have two options:

- Microsoft's DisplayMask API, which is surfaced in the [Xamarin.DuoSDK NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.DuoSDK). This is also targeted just at the Surface Duo - the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/surface-duo-sdk-xamarin-samples/) has Xamarin.Android samples showing how it works.
- The binding for Android's Jetpack Window Manager, in [Xamarin.AndroidX.Window NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Window/) (currently in alpha). This is the 'generic' API that will work on folding devices from multiple OEMs (eg. Samsung). Because it's still in alpha (as of April 2021), there aren't a lot of samples around but better support is coming.